# Assigning value to @Html.Hidden from value of @Html.DropDownList in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Sample Code:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Smth_ID", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Smth, "--Select Layer--", new { id = "list" })
@Html.Hidden("Smth_Description", <value from list above>);

@Html.DropDownList("Smth1_ID", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Smth1, "--Select Layer--", new { id = "list1" })
@Html.Hidden("Smth1_Description", <value from the list1 above>);
```

I pass data using ViewBag to my view from a controller. It has 2 drop down list where users can select 2 values(Smth_Description and Smth1_Description) which corresponds to Smth_ID and Smth1_ID respectively.

The issue is that I want to retrieve the values itself from the dropdownlist based on what was selected by the user. I intend to use a hidden field, but I'm not sure how to bind the selected values from the dropdownlists to the individual hidden fields.

Can someone help me out here?

Comment: If you use @Html.DropDownListFor(p=>p.Value) then this should yield a hidden field name for value.

Comment: Hi lrb, is it possible to return 2 hidden fields for a single @Html.DropDownListFor statement?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this you can either

1. Use a `@Html.DropDownListFor` instead of `@Html.DropDownList` for both dropdown lists. For this you need to change the viewbags into your model's properties.
2. If you want to use `ViewBag` and your hidden fields, in the on change event of dropdown assign the selected value of drop downs to corresponding hidden fields.

eg:

```
$('#list').change(function(){    
   $('#Smth_Description').val($('#list:selected').val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya  i suggests Ajax to do this . find the

```
control named =Smth1_ID
```

and the find also the 
     hiddentTextField using it ID= Smth1_Description

Then assign the the value of the first element to the hidden on

```
document ready of ajax call.
```

or 
     Javascript on bodyLoad()

```
 ------------------------------------------------------------------
 <script type='javascript'>
$( document ).ready(function() {
 var data = $("Smth1_ID").val();
 $("#Smth1_Description").prop("text",data.toString()) ;      
 });
 $('#Smth1_ID').change(function(){    
 $('#Smth_Description').val(this.val());
});

 </script>
```